# Customizable pagestyle with options using DeclarePageStyleByLayers

Tags: macros, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer}

\newcommand{\headerheight}{2cm}
\newcommand{\headertext}{\Huge\textcolor{red}{Header}}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  area={20pt}{30pt}{\paperwidth}{\headerheight},
  contents={%
    \parbox[c][\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{}
  }
]{layer1}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=layer1,
  contents={\headertext}
]{layer2}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{teststyle}{layer2, layer1}
\pagestyle{teststyle}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It produces a document with the word `Header` written on the top left corner of each page. Instead of that, I would like to make my pagestyle customizable, so that I could write something like this (the syntax may be different, but it gives a rough idea):

```
\pagestyle[headertitle = This is my title, leftshift = 40pt]{teststyle}
```

with commands that would be defined like this:

```
\newcommand{\headertext}[1]{\Huge\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  area={<leftshift (defined as 20pt by default)>}{<rightshift (defined as 30pt by default)>}{\paperwidth}{\headerheight},
  contents={%
    \parbox[c][\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{}
  }
]{layer1}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=layer1,
  contents={\headertext{<headertitle>}}
]{layer2}
```

Where the "variables" `leftshit`, `rightshift` and `headertitle` have been put in `<>` (just for illustration).

How to achieve something along that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why you want to define such a macro. But maybe the following suggestion helps to get what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer}

\newcommand*{\headerheight}{2cm}
\newcommand*{\headertext}{}
\newkomafont{headertext}{\Huge\color{red}}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  area={20pt}{30pt}{\paperwidth}{\headerheight},
  contents={%
    \parbox[c][\layerheight]{\layerwidth}{}% Why there is an empty parbox?
  }
]{layer1}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=layer1,
  ]{layer2}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{teststyle}{layer2, layer1}

\newcommand*\setpagestyle[2][]{%
  \RedeclareLayer[clone=layer1]{layer2}% reset layer2 as clone of layer1
  \ModifyLayer[#1,pretocontents=\usekomafont{headertext}]{layer2}% add the optional settings
  \pagestyle{#2}% set the pagestyle
}

\begin{document}
\setpagestyle[contents=Header]{teststyle}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\setpagestyle[hoffset=60pt,voffset=1cm,contents=This is my title]{teststyle}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\setpagestyle[contents=Header]{teststyle}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]